# Im trying to generate a CSR from our SharePoint page to a vendors website to pull information from them. Where am i supposed to generate the CSR from?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-keyvault, csr

Is it supposed to be done in Azure since its SharePoint or is it in a different server. I have looked into Azure Key Vault but before proceeding need confirmation if this is correct. And if so how to go about generating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the below points are helpful:

- For a simple way to create a CSR that works on any Microsoft server
  platform, you can use the DigiCert.Azure Key Vault partners with the
  following certificate authorities to simplify certificate creation.
  DigiCert, GlobalSign.(   offers OV TLS/SSL certificates with
  DigiCert /GlobalSign)
- Azure Key Vault supports storing digital certificates issued by any
  certificate authority (CA). It supports (CSR) with a private/public
  key pair.
- If you are a Microsoft azure user you can create csr in keyvault.`The thing we need to make sure is that the private key and resulting public key are a matching pair`.( AFAIK  CSR need not have to be
  generated on SharePoint. )
- One of the biggest advantage of managing certificates through Key
  Vault is the Private Key of the certificate is never exposed outside
  the Key Vault Security World. reference

> The Private Key would be stored within Key Vault, and Public Key would
> be attached to CSR and submitted to the CA.
>
> During certificate
> Import, the Public Key (attached with the certificate) would be
> matched against the Private Key (stored within Key Vault) to complete
> the Key Pair.

**Steps to generate csr in azure keyvault :**

1. Sign into the Azure portal and select the key vault where you wish
   to install your certificate.
2. Select Certificates in the right-hand Settings menu.
3. Click the Generate/Import button to open the Create a certificate
   window.
4. Enter or select the details in the Create a certificate form fields

> Select Certificate issued by a integrated CA / non- integrated CA and
> other fields Click the Create button to generate your new key pair and
> CSR.

5. And check this [blog](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/generate-csr-install-certificate-microsoft-azure-key-vault/) / [Creating and merging a certificate
   signing request in Azure Key Vault | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/certificates/create-certificate-signing-request?tabs=azure-portal#add-certificates-in-key-vault-issued-by-partnered-cas) for complete
   details of steps.
   [image]

**References:**

1. [Get started with Key Vault certificates | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/certificates/certificate-scenarios)
2. [Access SharePoint online content using Azure key vault certificate
   and Azure function app | Sundar’s blog (sundarcloud.com)](https://www.sundarcloud.com/2020/08/access-sharepoint-online-content-using.html)